# Jenkins - How to clone just the last changed files from GitLab

Tags: php, git, jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab

Is there a possibility to let Jenkins clone only the changed files from GitLab instead of the whole repository?

Comment: I am guessing you have not actually considered how GIT actually works, and what a `clone` actually does.

Comment: Why would one want to do that? That leaves you with a non usable clone!

Comment: You could do a shallow clone to only grab the newest commits, then if you really wanted, you should script a way to use git show to identify the changed files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** Don't do it, even if you find a way.

**Here is why:**

`git clone` is used when you don't have the repository locally and want to get one whole working copy of it.

`git pull` is used when you already have the repository cloned, and you only want to pull the newest changes.

`git pull` could potentially create merge conflicts, and dealing with those would require human intervention, and Jenkins is all about Automation, so `git clone` is preferred.

Jenkins deleting the repository and doing a fresh `git clone` also gives you the peace of mind that if your build works, it is because you have working code in your repository on GitLab and not because of something that Jenkins have saved from a previous build.